# SessionId null in Selenium RC test after redirect

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm testing an app, and after I've filled an extarnal payment service iframe I'm redirected to a payment confirmation screen inside the app I'm testing.

In selenium webdriver this confirmation windows is caught and all is fine, instead in Selenium RC there's an unexpected behaviour that trigger the confirmation page to be opened in a new browser window and every further Selenium command on this gives a SessionId null exception.

How can i pass the sessionid to the new window or solve the problem in some way.. eg. select that window etc.

Answer (score 0):

fist select the window using window id and den do your activities on det window.
I thin this may help.

```
wait_for_pop_up(locator, "300000")
select_window(locator)
window_focus()
select_window(null)
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the reply, indeed. 

Aruna, i haven't tested your suggestion yet but do you think it may work even without do changes to the payment method? I don't think i have the auth to do changes to the app code... Or can you expand the third point please.

Thanks again.

Comment: The solution will not work out if you cannot change the external payment method. The called external method should have an extra parameter for selenium object since the calling method passes it during invocation.